# Level shifter to Interface Microcontroller A/D channel

Tags: sensor, adc, interface

I need to interface speed monitoring signal to Micro controller A/D channel
[image: Sensor Output Waveform]. I am measuring speed by Electro Magnetic method.The frequency range is 100 HZ to 600 HZ and Amplitude is +/- 2V to 4V (Peak to Peak). I want low pass filter with level shifter single supply (5V)
op amp circuit.

Can any one help me suggest good solution?

Comment: Suggestion: create a circuit that converts the analog signal into a digital logic "pulse train" signal--i.e., convert each analog "blip" into a short duration digital logic pulse--and then use a microcontroller with a counter/timer circuit to measure the interval between successive pulses.

Comment: why do you want to low-pass filter it?

Comment: by eyeball the frequency of the signal shown on the scope looks like about 1Khz  although the repition rate is 100Hz,

Comment: What have you uncovered so far? Please also be clear about amplitudes.... +/- 2V is 4Vp-p most folk would say and I suspect that your minimum amplitude is certainly lower than 4Vp-p at 100 Hz.

Comment: is 2 V always guaranteed and 4 V is the maximum expected out of the measurement block? Do you want to connect it to ADC channel? Why?

Answer (score 1):

Something simple like this should make it easy enough to count the pulses:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuSVY1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the idea is to rectify the pulse, feed it into a Schmitt Trigger and the use an interrupt on the micro controller to count the pulses. In the schematic there is an inverting not gate. This is meant to be representative of a 74HC14 hex inverting Schmitt trigger. These are very cheap and very common. The inversion makes no difference to the solution since the interrupt on the micro controller will trigger on a HIGH to LOW instead of a LOW to HIGH.

Since the voltage swing is potentially small, you may want to consider using a Schottky diode to reduce the effect of the diodes forward voltage. Also make sure that the rectified voltage is enough to trigger the Schmitt Trigger.

EDIT: For this to work, you would need to remove the DC bias from the signal by adding a capacitor in series with the diode.